# RSS Validator and "Server returned HTTP Error 302" Error

Tags: php, web, rss

I have a php file in my site that create my rss, and I can see result by browser. But when I want to check by **https://validator.w3.org/feed/**, I got this error:

> Server returned HTTP Error 302: The HTTP server returned a redirect
>   error that would lead to an infinite loop

and when I want to get rss by file_get_contents, I got this error:

> failed to open stream: Redirection limit reached, ...

please help to solve this problem. thanks everybody ;)

> I solved my problem, the problem was ModSecurity :)

Comment: I would submit that as the answer an accept it so future readers are able to find it.

Comment: A 302 is not an error, it is a temp. redirect.    Did you redirect to yourself?